# How do I get status code of the response in case of an error?

Tags: go, http

I am making requests using `http/net` package. Here is an example:

```
response, err := http.DefaultClient.Do(req)
```

But I found out that I have no way to know the status code in case of an error:

```
response, err := http.DefaultClient.Do(req)

if err != nil {
    if response.StatusCode === 503 { ... } // repsonse is nil 
    else {
       return []byte{}, err
    }
}
```

But I am quite sure that there must be a way, looks like I am missing something obvious

Comment: If you have a non-`nil` error, most likely `response` is not usable. If you have an HTTP 503 response, `err` will be `nil` and you _can_ check `response.StatusCode`.

Comment: If there is an error you do not receive a response thus there is no status code.

Comment: In general, if `err` is not `nil`, you do not have an HTTP response (so you can't speak about an HTTP response code), and you must not touch / use `response`. If `err` is `nil`, then you may go ahead and use / read `response`, first by checking the status.

Answer (score 1):

When an error occurs, the response object will be nil, and directly accessing the status code from a nil response object will result in a runtime error.
It means your code is failing to make the request. Try logging the error and always make sure to access the status code outside of the `if err != nil` block.